# Basic jquery dropdown menu, stop it from constantly opening/closing

Tags: jquery, html, menu

```
<div id="mNavigator" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:30px;color:#888;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:400,font-size:11px;letter-spacing:0;opacity:0.6;cursor:pointer;padding:18px;z-index:9999;background:red;">
You are browsing <span style="color:#fff">MYNAME</span>
</div>

<div id="dropDown" style="display:none;padding:8px;background:#1b1b1b;position:absolute;top:40px;right:40px;z-index:9999;">
<div style="width:319px;padding:8px 10px 8px 10px;background:#000;font-size:9px;font-family:helvetica,arial;color:#666;">MY HEADER</div>
</div>

$('#mNavigator').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
    $('#dropDown').show('fast', function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','0.6');
    $('#dropDown').hide('fast', function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Ive created a basic drowndown menu, and I had two questions was hoping an expert could help with

1) How can I stop the menu from close when you try to mouse onto the actual menu items (the part that says MY HEADER)
2) If you move your mouse around the red area, the menu very quickly keeps cycling, which results in a poor user experience, any way around this?

Ive included my example in jsfiddle for ease:  http://jsfiddle.net/ECreX/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your HTML inside a DIV element `<div id="mNav"></div>`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ECreX/9/)**</kbd>

and use:

```
$('#mNav').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ) {
    var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter',
        opacity  = mEnt ? 1 : 0.6 ,
        showHide = mEnt ? 'show' : 'hide' ;
    $('#mNavigator').stop().fadeTo(300, opacity);
    $('#dropDown').stop()[showHide](400);
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put the submenu as a child of the main menu div, and use .mousenter() and .mouseleave() instead of .mouseover() and .mouseout(), it fixes the issue. Alternately you can use .hover() which is a shortcut for .mouseenter() and .mouseleave(). Also note that by nesting the submenu div, that the main menu stays active when the mouse is over the submenu.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ECreX/7/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="mNavigator" style="position:absolute;top:0px;right:30px;color:#888;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:400,font-size:11px;letter-spacing:0;opacity:0.6;cursor:pointer;padding:18px;z-index:9999;background:red;">You are browsing <span style="color:#fff">MYNAME</span>
    <div id="dropDown"
    style="display:none;padding:8px;background:#1b1b1b;position:absolute;top:40px;right:40px;z-index:9999;">
        <div style="width:319px;padding:8px 10px 8px 10px;background:#000;font-size:9px;font-family:helvetica,arial;color:#666;">MY HEADER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#mNavigator').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    $('#dropDown').show('fast', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.6');
    $('#dropDown').hide('fast', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Nesting the menu is my preferred pattern. You can inherently avoid bubbling issues.

Comment: you should use `stop()` too before the animation.

Comment: @deadlock - true, adding .stop() would help the animation queue from builing up and causing any potential latent cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.stop()` on line 3 to cancel queuing of the animations, and leave the menu open as long as the menu has focus:

```
$('#mNavigator, #dropDown').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
    $('#dropDown').stop().show('fast', function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#mNavigator').css('opacity','0.6');
    $('#dropDown').hide('fast', function() {
     // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/ECreX/5/

Comment: why don't you use `stop()` in the `mouseout` event too. It will give a nicer animation.